# Ubuntu 23.04 new install no permission to write home directory

Tags: 23.04

I’ve just installed 23.04 fresh to my whole drive using a bootable USB and am unable to write to my user directory without sudo. None of the usual Documents, Downloads, etc, directories exist either.

Additionally I cannot open Firefox so am having to use my phone.

I’d expect a new install to at least have the basic functionality working. What’s likely to have gone wrong?

Comment: How did you "install"? What's your UID? `id` to see. What's the ownership/permissions of your home directory? `ls -ld $HOME`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: I solved the problem by installing Manjaro. But I had to disable secure boot. Will try 23.04 again tomorrow although I thought it supported secure boot. If same problems occur, I can certainly post the requested info.

Comment: I tried with secure boot off; same problem. I was able to resolve using the legacy installer, selecting no third-party drivers and a minimal install. Doesn't answer why the other installs failed, so not really an answer to my own question.

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem. What the hell?? It seems to happen when choosing to creation the partition table manually. I did nothing very complex though, I just chose to create a specific partition for `/home`, which I already did in the past without any trouble